# Rearrange fields in crystal report (in bulk)

Tags: crystal-reports, field, crystal-reports-2008

1. I have a report with about 20 fields and 1 group by field. When I create a new report and follow the wizard, it helps me create the complete report but all the field are really cramped in togather. They are not really usable in its default layout. I would like to rearrange them (increase size, and move them apart). Can I do that in Crystal Report by selecting multiple fields and change the size. Is there a work around?
2. Another option for me would be to have all the fields layout on page page sidwise and an top of eachother as if in a table. This actually does look pretty and professional except that headers are missing in this case. Since I am using group by and 1 group contains about 1-5 records, this layout really suits me. Any suggestion what you do when you too many fields in  a Crystal Report. I am new to Crystal.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can rearrange all the field into crystal report design. you can change the page size from portrait to Landscape. Default wizard provided you some default design. you can change all things after the completing wizard.